# Is it okay to free multiple dynamically allocated memories at once?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

During my school assignments, I just got curious if it really frees as I expect.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void main(){
    int* menu1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* menu2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* menu3 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* menu4 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* menu5 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    free(menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4,menu5);
    system("pause");
}
```

It still runs in VS2017, but I'm not sure that it's freed correctly.

Comment: Does this even compile? `free((menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4,menu5));` would, and only the memory associated with `menu5` would be released. Methinks you are running the previous build of the code, which was compilable.

Comment: It might run, but no, it doesn't free right.

Comment: This might run because VS2017 uses a s**t C compiler from 1989. I bet it doesn't find the user-defined library `"stdlib.h"` (rather than `<stdlib.h>`) so it makes up the functions malloc and free. Since you cast the result of malloc you hide the bug. What happens if you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: Notably, a conforming C compiler _must_  go check `<stdlib.h>` if it doesn't find `"stdlib.h"`, as per C11 6.10.2. However, VS is not a conforming C compiler so all bets are off.

Comment: "During my school assignments"... **wow**. You should consider gifting a copy of K&R's "The C Programming Language" to your professor.

Comment: If you actually make it compile, run it under a memory checker like Valgrind (I'm not sure what the equivalent is on Microsoft platforms, but one should exist).

Answer (score 2):

for each pointer you have, you allocated memory separately. By memory allocation, the system allocates a bit more that requested in order to safe some control information which should be used for different internal purposes and also later for deallocation.

Since each allocated memory knows only about itself and not about other allocated pieces of memory, you cannot free all together.

The function free expects only one argument (one pointer). Please see 7.22.3.3 in C standard.

GCC doesn't compile this code.

Answer (score 2):

No.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/free

```
void free(void *ptr);
```

I code does not compile:

```
error: too many arguments to function ‘free’
  free(menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4,menu5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compile, because the function `free()` expects one argument, but you passed more than that; `5` to be exact.

You could make it compile by enclosing the arguments in parentheses:

```
free((menu1, menu2, menu3, menu4, menu5));
```

This allows all the arguments to be evaluated by using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), but only the last one will be used by the function `free()`. That is, only `menu5` will be freed, and the rest won't.

You must call `free()` on each argument separately to release memory appropriately:

```
free(menu1);
free(menu2);
...
free(menu5);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code as is, will not compile:

```
  free(menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4,menu5); /* error: too many arguments to function 'free' */
```

The function `free` is defined in header `<stdlib.h>` and takes only one parameter:

```
void free( void* ptr );
```

Parameters:

```
 `ptr` -    pointer to the memory to deallocate
```

Return value:

`(none)`

Function deallocates the space previously allocated by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `aligned_alloc`, (since `C11`) or `realloc()`.
If `ptr` is a `null` pointer, the function does nothing.

References:

```
C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011):
7.22.3.3 The free function (p: 348)

C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999):
7.20.3.2 The free function (p: 313)

C89/C90 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1990):
4.10.3.2 The free function
```

Answer (score 0):

If this compiles you are using an olde compiler. What you are showing is a common error in C code.

What happens in this case the generated code looks something like this:

```
PUSH  menu5 ; which probably looks more like "menu5(SP)"
PUSH  menu4
PUSH  menu3
PUSH  menu2
PUSH  menu1
CALL _free
```

free () only expects one argument and it finds an argument: menu1. The extra arguments simply get ignored.

What would cause even bigger problems is to not pass enough arguments to a function. In that case the function being called would use random garbage on the stack as the argument. Something like

```
 fprintf (fp)
```

in rarely executed logging code could give you a crash.